# Qt - How to add QTCPSocket to the pending connections of QTCPServer

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I have a simple multithreading application that works like the example  ["Threaded Fortune Server Example"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html) on Qt website.

When my *QTCPServer* receive an incoming connection, I create a *QRunnable* task, passing the *socketDescritptor* and then submitting it to a *QThreadPool*:

```
void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    Task *task = new Task(socketDescriptor, this);
    this->m_pool->start(task);
}
```

then in the Task method `run()` I create the socket:

```
void Task::run()
{
    QTcpSocket tcpSocket;
    if (!tcpSocket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        emit error(tcpSocket.error());
        return;
    } 
...
}
```

However, I read those note about *incomingConnection* method of *QTCPServer* 
 from the  [Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection)

> **Note**: If another socket is created in the reimplementation of this method, it needs to be added to the Pending Connections mechanism by calling addPendingConnection().
>
> **Note**: If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new QTcpSocket
>   object in another thread you have to pass the socketDescriptor to the
>   other thread and create the QTcpSocket object there and use its
>   setSocketDescriptor() method.

So, my questions are:

- how can I add the socket created from another
  thread to the pending connection of the Server?
- is this a *needful* operation?

Thanks,

Comment: Your code should be fine, you are not relying on the `nextPendingConnection()` mechanism or the `newConnection()` signal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sometimes, my application crash with "QThreadPipe: Unable to create pipe: Too many open files", expecially when the number of the incoming connection increasing. I was wondering why this happens.